# What is a good free skeletal animated model format?

Tags: 3d, modeling, file-format

I'm wondering what a good skeletal animated model format (Like milkshape 3d) that is free to use in a commercial product. Think ogg (What I'm looking for in a model file format)  to mp3 (What I think I have in milkshape 3d)

Comment: *.b3d from OpenPerformer would be something that is OSS afaik. But it's an ascii-based format, so it can get quite large and parsing takes its time. Also I don't think there's any proprietary tech in the milkshape format. Milkshape may not be OSS but that doesn't automatically mean that you need a license of Milkshape to use the format.

Comment: Most model formats (FBX, etc) support bones and skinning. Is there some other specific feature that you require?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend IQE / IQM. (Inter Quake Export / Inter Quake Model)
IQE is human readable and in comparison to COLLADA not bloated.

https://github.com/lsalzman/iqm

To export iqe from blender,name file ending in exporter settings to .iqe in blender, else you will get a binary .iqm file.

IQE sample copied together:

```
# Inter-Quake Export

joint "hips" -1
    pq -0.03245495 -0.05330581 1.73601806 -0.55081493 -0.55081868 -0.44338924 -0.44340476 1.71911621 1.71900940 1.71911621
joint "spine" 0
    pq -0.00000000 0.17790578 0.00000002 0.05466786 -0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.99850458
joint "thigh.L" 0
    pq 0.09800000 0.06980889 0.02854794 -0.98937774 -0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.14536750
joint "thigh.R" 0
    pq -0.09800000 0.06980889 0.02854794 -0.98937774 -0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.14536750
joint "chest" 1
    pq -0.00000000 0.15899009 0.00000002 0.07025049 -0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.99752939
joint "shin.L" 2
    pq -0.00000000 0.53636950 0.00000001 -0.08754126 -0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.99616098
joint "shin.R" 3
    pq 0.00000000 0.53636950 0.00000001 -0.08754126 -0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.99616098
joint "neck" 4
    pq -0.00000000 0.31659144 -0.00000000 -0.15932408 0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.98722643
joint "shoulder.L" 4
    pq 0.01830000 0.26075083 0.07790685 0.60322601 0.34475890 0.35720304 -0.62423211
joint "shoulder.R" 4
    pq -0.01830000 0.26075083 0.07790685 0.60322601 -0.34475890 -0.35720301 -0.62423211
joint "foot.L" 5
    pq -0.00000001 0.45421475 0.00000000 0.52736372 -0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.84963965
joint "heel.L" 5
    pq -0.00000001 0.45421475 0.00000000 -0.00000108 -0.95491695 -0.29687306 -0.00000349
joint "foot.R" 6
    pq -0.00000001 0.45421475 0.00000000 0.52736372 -0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.84963965


mesh "Plane"
    material "Materialfemale_head_diffuse"

vp 0.30406725 -0.06851297 3.15646553
    vt 0.16116023 0.91230547
    vn 0.77198696 -0.09305351 -0.62879014
    vb 14 0.06331210 9 0.22773869 16 0.02638610
vp 0.30295858 -0.06872851 3.15225410
    vt 0.15831752 0.91323620
    vn 0.74249125 -0.05713115 0.66741502
    vb 14 0.06448569 9 0.23067474 16 0.03089154
vp 0.30062246 -0.09316005 3.15278101
    vt 0.15223879 0.89753073
    vn 0.68772942 -0.32591927 0.64869481
    vb 14 0.06387292 9 0.22933370 16 0.04849536
vp 0.30173114 -0.09175216 3.15699244
    vt 0.15537374 0.89735889
    vn 0.73992944 -0.18613447 -0.64641970
    vb 14 0.06253068 9 0.22597092 16 0.04049119
vp 0.28714117 -0.11721295 3.14981532
    vt 0.14215131 0.88140124
    vn 0.68051898 -0.30143905 0.66785353
    vb 14 0.06330740 9 0.22821900 16 0.08076507
vp 0.28824985 -0.11580504 3.15402675
    vt 0.14528604 0.88122898
    vn 0.78907448 -0.34746140 -0.50658852
    vb 14 0.06223779 9 0.22557993 16 0.07143287
vp 0.27718475 -0.14343289 3.15052891
    vt 0.13443437 0.86377084
    vn 0.78205103 -0.62231439 -0.03347941
    vb 14 0.06145519 9 0.22470905 16 0.11559944
vp 0.40598029 -0.07009319 2.06394410
    vt 0.51144719 0.65078229
    vn 0.96516240 -0.03048846 0.25986901
    vb 39 0.05125554 49 0.06447156 9 0.09062786 16 0.10200738 22 0.40442598
vp 0.51175433 -0.06866921 1.76034880
    vt 0.51144719 0.65078229
    vn 0.94395953 -0.02969521 0.32872257
    vb 49 0.08526595 59 0.01701071 9 0.07708146 16 0.08161286 22 0.40676904 39 0.07483290
vp 0.50648546 -0.23342589 1.76058435
    vt 0.39425191 0.64811873
    vn 0.92233139 -0.18247645 0.34059823
    vb 49 0.09114462 59 0.02344448 9 0.06846331 16 0.07819787 22 0.41013628 39 0.08135859
vp 0.40198454 -0.19504040 2.06412268
    vt 0.39425191 0.64811873
    vn 0.94628024 -0.17823252 0.26979029
    vb 49 0.06479627 9 0.08399796 16 0.09960886 22 0.41896838 39 0.05181086
vp 0.37398952 -0.07167916 2.23059535
    vt 0.51144719 0.65078229
    vn 0.99947500 -0.03228937 -0.00265518
    vb 49 0.05364015 9 0.08941103 14 0.03047995 16 0.13284177 22 0.38033959 39 0.02502382
vp 0.37042767 -0.18305929 2.23075438
    vt 0.39425191 0.64811873
    vn 0.98346823 -0.18106805 -0.00213632
    vb 49 0.05493407 9 0.10579350 14 0.02137030 16 0.14178413 22 0.39620858 39 0.02357950
vp 0.39763987 -0.07091631 2.34959197
    vt 0.51144719 0.65078229
    vn 0.98996693 -0.03247194 -0.13751744
    vb 49 0.03959022 9 0.14956860 14 0.06598662 8 0.00458327 16 0.15160930 22 0.34660584 39 0.00838437
vp 0.39376482 -0.18739590 2.34976530
    vt 0.39425191 0.64811873
    vn 0.97401547 -0.17539300 -0.14328694
    vb 49 0.04173237 16 0.15113261 9 0.15110129 14 0.06062943 22 0.35898554 39 0.00605630
vp 0.40973425 -0.07450260 2.50229096
    vt 0.51144719 0.65078229
    vn 0.99719590 -0.03210559 0.06759875
    vb 49 0.01431185 16 0.15112750 9 0.15112750 8 0.03083992 14 0.10953382 22 0.28819847
vp 0.40566102 -0.20187411 2.50247335
    vt 0.39425191 0.64811873
    vn 0.98079377 -0.18519020 0.06122141
    vb 49 0.01297742 16 0.15112752 9 0.15112749 14 0.10090467 8 0.01842275 22 0.29911554


fm 0 1 2
fm 0 2 3
fm 3 2 4
fm 3 4 5
fm 5 4 6
fm 7 8 9
fm 7 9 10
fm 11 7 10
fm 11 10 12
fm 13 11 12
fm 13 12 14
fm 15 13 14
fm 15 14 16
fm 17 15 16
fm 17 16 18
fm 19 17 18
fm 19 18 20
fm 21 19 20
fm 21 20 22
fm 23 21 22
fm 23 22 24
fm 25 23 24
fm 24 22 26
fm 25 24 27
fm 28 25 27
fm 24 26 29
fm 27 24 29
fm 28 27 30
fm 31 28 30
fm 26 32 29
fm 26 33 32
fm 31 30 34
fm 35 31 34
fm 33 36 32
fm 33 37 36


animation "idle"
    framerate 24.00000000

frame
pq -0.03245495 -0.05330581 1.73601806 -0.55081493 -0.55081868 -0.44338924 -0.44340476 1.71911621 1.71900940 1.71911621
pq 0.00000000 0.17790566 -0.00000001 0.05466786 -0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.99850458
pq 0.09800000 0.06980877 0.02854792 -0.98937774 -0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.14536764
pq -0.09800000 0.06980877 0.02854792 -0.98937774 -0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.14536764
pq -0.00000000 0.15899020 0.00000000 0.07025050 -0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.99752945
pq 0.00000001 0.53636932 0.00000000 -0.08754127 -0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.99616098
pq 0.00000000 0.53636932 0.00000000 -0.08754127 -0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.99616098
pq 0.00000000 0.31659144 0.00000000 -0.15932409 -0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.98722643
pq 0.01830000 0.26075083 0.07790685 0.60322601 0.34475884 0.35720304 -0.62423211
pq -0.01830000 0.26075083 0.07790685 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a wholly open format, your best bet is probably [COLLADA](https://www.khronos.org/collada/).  The [OpenCOLLADA](https://code.google.com/p/opencollada/) project hosts exporters and other goodies.

Here's the catch, though:  It will work well for use in tools, but I do not suggest loading it directly in a game, because -- like FBX -- it is an *exchange* format, and exchange formats are inherently (and necessarily) bloated.

For delivery, most of the pros will suggest rolling your own custom binary format that will load efficiently into your specific game.

I know that's not the answer you want to hear!  So, here are some lazy-time-tips: If you're using an engine, it may have a preferred format to use (such as Ogre3D's binary mesh format).  Alternatively, if you're rolling your own engine, some 3D modeling programs (such as Cheetah3D) will export straight into a C header file, if you are using a language that can take advantage of that.